# How to sort queryset based on foreign key with no duplicates

Tags: django, django-queryset

I would like to feature the 5 most recently reviewed books on my website. I am trying to order the books based on the time they were reviewed. The problem is if a book has recently been reviewed more than once, it will appear more than once. How do I get 5 unique books from this query? (I tried adding .distinct() to the query and it didn't work!)

`reviewed = Book.objects.order_by('-review__date_posted')[:5]`

Comment: How does your Book model and Review model look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can order by the largest `date_posted` of the `review`, so:

```
from django.db.models import Max

Book.objects.annotate(
    last_review=Max('review__date_posted')
).order_by('-last_review')[:5]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.distinct('review')`