# Django ORM dublicate objects in queryset after order_by by foreignkey field

Tags: python, django

I have encountered some unexpected sorting behaviour with objects. As soon as I sort by the related model field, I get duplicates.
A short description of the model fields

models.py

```
class GoogleCreativeSpend(models.Model):
    creative = models.ForeignKey(
        'GoogleCreative',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    spend = models.DecimalField()

class GoogleCreative(CreamCreative):
     .....
```

Create some objects:

```
>>> creative = GoogleCreative.objects.get(name='gs_video1031v1')
>>> spend = GoogleCreativeSpend(creative=creative, spend=100,)
>>> spend.save()
>>> spend = GoogleCreativeSpend(creative=creative, spend=1100,)
>>> spend.save()
>>> spend = GoogleCreativeSpend(creative=creative, spend=1,)
>>> spend.save()
```

**views.py**

```
queryset = GoogleCreative.objects.all()
queryset.order_by('googlecreativespend__spend')
for i in queryset:     
    if i.name == 'gs_video1031v1':
        print(i.name)  


| gs_video1031v1
| gs_video1031v1
| gs_video1031v1
```

I.e. by creating 3 googlespend objects I get 3 duplicates for googlecreative after sorting.

According to [How to sort queryset based on foreign key with no duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66584657/how-to-sort-queryset-based-on-foreign-key-with-no-duplicates)
I tryied

```
queryset.distinct()
```

and

```
queryset.distinct('googlecreativespend__spend')
```

But it doesn't work

How to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Finde the solution using Avg

```
queryset = queryset.annotate(spend=Avg('googlecreativespend__spend'))
queryset.order_by('spend')
```

upd

Be careful, using Avg with values equal to None leads to unpredictable sorting results. The solution is to add a default value

```
queryset = queryset.annotate(
            spend=Coalesce(Avg('googlecreativespend__spend'), 0, output_field=DecimalField())
        )
```